# what region does the Laurent series converge?

Tags: complex-analysis

If a Laurent series in powers of $ \ z \ $ for the function $ \large \ f(z) =\frac{e^z(z+1)}{(z-2)^2 \sin z} \ $ converges at $ \ z=3 \ $,

**what region does the Laurent series converge** ?

**Answer:**

Since the Laurent series converges at $ \ z=3 \ $ , we can express $ \  f(z)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n (z-3)^3 \ $ , where

$ a_n= \large \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z|=3} \frac{f(z)}{(z-3)^{n+1}} dz . $

**But how to find the region of convergence ?**

**Is there any help ?**

Comment: Do you mean a *Laurent's  series*?

Comment: What happened when you expanded into a power series in $u=z-3$ the function $$\frac{e^{3+u}(4+u)}{(1+u)^2\sin(3+u)}\ ?$$

Comment: What? $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 2):

No need to compute the coefficients of the series. The convergence region of a laurent series is determined by the poles of a fucntion. The fucntions ploes are at $\{2\}\cup \{n\pi\}$. Hence the domain of convergence will be

$\{z\in\mathbb{C}| 2<|z|<\pi\}$

It is this domain, because $3\in\{z\in\mathbb{C}| 2<|z|<\pi\}$

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is meromorph, so the convergence radius at 3 is the distance between 3 and the closest pole of $f$. You can find some details about that in the book from Amar and Matheron.
Then here, you just have to find the poles of $f$ and especially the one closer to 3, which is $\pi$.
Thus the series converges exactly on $D(3,\pi-3)$.

Comment: The pole at $\pi$ seems closer to $3$ than $2$.

Comment: You have a cool name to answer ;), but there is an aditional pole at $\pi$, which will change your convergence radius. Furthermore the laurent series is in powers of $z$, so it is a not centerd around $3$

Comment: Ah I forgot $\pi$... of course.
Are you sure the Laurent series is in power of $z$ ? What is the point of developping it around $z=3$?

Comment: @AdrienLaurent in fact i'm not 100% sure which one is searched by OP. However both our solutions are correct answers to certain questions. I claim that mine is the correct answer because: 1. your's is "not really" a laurent series, as all negative exponents vanish (and the question looks like a schoolbook question). 2. your's is not in powers of $z$.

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak Yes I agree with you. But I think the answer should be a region like $r\leq |z-3|\leq R$ as you can find on wikipedia... I will look in my books to be sure.

Comment: Ok. So as $f$ is holomorphic in $D(3,\pi-3)$, the Laurent series converges on this disk. So my answer is right.
Then the difference in our anwers lies just in the point where we developed the function.